# Conditional join in dynamic table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a simple query with a join of 4 tables. It is working fine and now I need to add one more join in that query, but this time the table varies according the one parameter within that query;

My query looks like following:

```
SELECT pat.Id,dgroup.Diagnosis as 'Description', ntest.Testname as 'TestName',
       dgroup.Id as 'ProrityId', subt.TestSubType, **ntest.SubGroupId**
  from pat.tbl_PatientTestRecord pat
          JOIN tbl_Test_DiagnosisGroup InTest on pat.IndividualTestId=InTest.Id
          JOIN tbl_NrlTests nTest ON InTest.TestId=nTest.id
          JOIN tbl_DiagnosisGroup dgroup ON Intest.DGId=dgroup.id
          Left Join 
             **tbl_vary**
```

- **tbl_vary** depends on the **ntest.subgroupID**. and there are probably 3 tables that may appear in `tbl_vary`.

Since, my SQL is a little bit weak, I will be very thankful for the appropriate solution for this.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What you are asking is very vendor specific.

Comment: @peterm i am using sql server 2012..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be a UNION sub-query:

```
SELECT pat.Id,dgroup.Diagnosis as 'Description', ntest.Testname as 'TestName',
       dgroup.Id as 'ProrityId', subt.TestSubType, **ntest.SubGroupId**
  FROM pat.tbl_PatientTestRecord pat
  JOIN tbl_Test_DiagnosisGroup InTest on pat.IndividualTestId=InTest.Id
  JOIN tbl_NrlTests nTest ON InTest.TestId=nTest.id
  JOIN tbl_DiagnosisGroup dgroup ON Intest.DGId=dgroup.id
  LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT v1.SubGroupId, v1.Relevant_Col_1 AS rc1, v1.Relevant_Col_2 AS rc2
          FROM table_variant_1 AS v1
         WHERE v1.SubGroupId = ntest.SubGroupID
        UNION
        SELECT v2.SubGroupId, v2.Alternative_1 AS rc1, v2.Alternative_2 AS rc2
          FROM table_variant_2 AS v2
         WHERE v2.SubGroupId = ntest.SubGroupID
        UNION
        SELECT v3.SubGroupId, v3.Other_Source_1 AS rc1, v3.Other_Source_2 AS rc2
          FROM table_variant_3 AS v3
         WHERE v3.SubGroupId = ntest.SubGroupID
       ) AS u
    ON u.SubGroupId = ntest.SubGroupId
```

You might be better off without the WHERE clause in the sub-queries, or there might be other ways to specify the joins with the UNION-query...you've not provided all that many clues as to how the sub-queries should be constructed.